# How to update and maintain viewer state through different executions in eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to maintain viewer state in Eclipse even the eclipse project is closed. Also I need to update the 
viewer like if I am reloading it from eclipse menu.

Using viewer.refresh() just refreshes the tableviewer that I have inside it but it doesn't update it (re-running the code for filling the columns). 
I tried to use viewer.update(param1,param2) but I don't know what is param2, actually what is the right one.
This update can be done manually by reloading the view from Window->Show view->Other. How can I done this programatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reset the data displayed in the table you must call `TableViewer.setInput(xxx)` again with the data you want to display.

Comment: It doesn't work....I call it like this : viewer.setInput(ModelProvider.INSTANCE.getRow()); , until now the only way to reload the table with updated information is by rebuilding the project...

Comment: You must give setInput all the rows not just one row.

Comment: I used this :  ViewPart2.viewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
      ViewPart2.viewer.setInput(ModelProvider.INSTANCE); now the table is cleared but it is not refilled with the updated information. I tried to call this with my table being empty and it works. But if it is already filled and I call this it gives me a null exception, what could be the cause ?

Comment: setInput must be given an array or List of rows, presumably ModelProvider.INSTANCE is just an instance of ModelProvider which is not an array / List.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my getRow() method returns the list with the rows....the call viewer.setInput(ModelProvider.INSTANCE.getRow());  does what I expect only if the table is cleared before this call (so this will be the first call of modelprovider) but it doesn't at the second call (when the table is filled with information before the call), do you know what is the cause of this problem ?

Comment: I found that when I call getRow() setInput returns the rows already created. How to make setInput to recreate the array lists and implicitly the row list ?

Comment: TableViewer never changes anything in the model, you must update the model in your ModelProvider code.